# Add attribute to a Collection while reading csv file with CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv

I use C# CsvHelper to read the following csv-file:

> CSV-File Order:

ID;Message

```
0;Hello World
1;Foobar
```

My classes for the needed objects look like this. I need a collection of Text because after reading the csv file, I will add more messages to my Foobar object...

> Foobar-Class:

```
public int ID {get;set;}

public ICollection<Text> Texts {get;set;}

public Foobar()
{
  Texts = new List<Text>();
}
```

> Text-Class:

```
 public int ID {get;set;}
 public string Message {get;set;}
```

My mapping for CsvHelper is

> CsvClassMap of Foobar:

```
Map(m => m.ID).Index(0);
**Map(m => m.Texts).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField<Text>("Message", 1));**
```

But Csvhelper doesn't add the message to Foobar's Collection. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use my project below which adds the csv to a table.  Then you can add rows to the table after the file is read.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace CSVImporter
{

    public partial class CSVImporter : Form
    {
        //const string xmlfilename = @"C:\Users\fenwky\XmlDoc.xml";
        const string xmlfilename = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        DataSet ds = null;
        public CSVImporter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Create a Open File Dialog Object.
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;


            //doc.InsertBefore(xDeclare, root);
            // Create a CSV Reader object.
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader();

            ds = reader.ReadCSVFile(fileName, true);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];

        }
        private void WXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WriteXML();

        }
        public void WriteXML()
        {

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            ds.WriteXml(new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter), XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

            string xmlStr = stringWriter.ToString();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlStr);


            XmlDeclaration xDeclare = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);

            doc.InsertBefore(xDeclare, doc.FirstChild);

            // Create a procesing instruction.
            //XmlProcessingInstruction newPI;
            //String PItext = "<abc:stylesheet xmlns:abc=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">";
            //String PItext = "type='text/xsl' href='book.xsl'";
            string PItext = "html xsl:version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"";
            XmlText newPI =  doc.CreateTextNode(PItext);
            //newPI = docCreateProcessingInstruction("html", PItext);
            //newPI = doc.CreateComment(CreateDocumentType("html", PItext, "", "");
            doc.InsertAfter(newPI, doc.FirstChild);
            doc.Save(xmlfilename);

            XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
            myXslTrans.Load(xmlfilename);
            string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlfilename);
            myXslTrans.Transform(xmlfilename, directoryPath + "result.html");
            webBrowser1.Navigate(directoryPath + "result.html");

        }



    }
    public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```